# AppStore and PlayStore URL not working as expected?

Tags: android, ios, url, mobile, captiveportal

I'm working on captive portal and i have a page that has button that redirect the user to AppStore or PlayStore. but i encountered some problems.
The first one with the iOS devices: When i use this link `https://apps.apple.com/tn/app/instagram/id389801252` and i add the FQDN "apps.apple.com" in the walled garden. is not working it require internet connection, but i want a solution doesn't require internet connection at least for few seconds.

The second problem is that with devices that has Android 11 this this link `http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.instagram.android` redirect the user to the PlayStore on the browser not the mobile app , and this link "market://details?id=com.google.earth" require internet connection to work.
There's some solutions that i can proceed to accomplish this work.

Comment: Apple App Store and Google Play Store (in web browser or app) always require internet connection.